# Java, check is substring of string doesn't "exist"

Tags: java, string, exception, substring

I have a while loop that is supposed to seperate a word into individual letters... It works but then when ever i try to check if a substring that does not exist is null it throws exceptions...

```
    private static void seperateWord(String word) {
    boolean running = true;
    int count = 0;
    while (running) {
        if (word.substring(count, count + 1).equals("null")) {
            running = false;
            return;
        } else {
            letter[count] = word.substring(count, count + 1);
            System.out.println(letter[count]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

It does output all the letters correctly until it gets to the end of the string and has nothing left to read... as in it just does not exist. It throws this exception...

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at Class.seperateWord(Class.java:33)
at Class.main(Class.java:13)
```

Line 33 is :: if (input.substring(count, count + 1).equals("null")) {

Line 13 is just where I call the method.

The text I entered is "abc"

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is `input`, `word` and `letter` in this code? This is not anywhere near reall code sample.

Comment: Either you have a `String` of infinite length, or you may want to stop when you hit the end of it.

Comment: I know input was a variable i created for the whole class i changed it to word like it should be...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to get the substring going from index 3 to index 4 on a string which has only 3 characters. This is why you get an exception.

Moreover, `input.substring(count, count + 1).equals("null")` will obviously never be true. How could a string of 1 character ever be equal to the string `"null"`, which has 4 characters?

Read the API doc of the String class. It has a `length()` method which returns the length of the string, and that you should use to stop your loop. It also has a `charAt()` method which returns the character at a given index.